# How to deploy multiple ml models with scoring file using azure ml cli

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-ml-pipelines

I'm trying to deploy the Multiple azure ml models from workspace with scoring script file but i'm unable to deploy 2 models with azure ml cli

```
 az ml model deploy --name multi-model --model '[model1:9,model2:1]' --compute-target 'aks-cpu' --ic inferenceConfig.json -e 'inferen
ce-env' --ev 6 --dc aksDeploymentConfig.json -g 'Workspace' --workspace-name 'MLWorkspace' --as true --mi 1 --ma 2 --overwrite -v
```

But got error:
**{'Azure-cli-ml Version': '1.41.0', 'Error': WebserviceException:
Message: ModelNotFound: Model with id [model1:9,model2:1] not found in provided workspace
InnerException None
ErrorResponse
{
"error": {
"message": "ModelNotFound: Model with id [model1:9,model2:1] not found in provided workspace"
}
}}**

But i'm able to deploy single model without issue
For multi-models, i am able to do with python without any issue i.e.,

```
aks_service_name='modelsvc' 
aks_service = Model.deploy(ws,
models=[model1,model2],
inference_config=inference_config,
deployment_config=gpu_aks_config,
deployment_target=aks_target,
name=aks_service_name,overwrite=True)

aks_service.wait_for_deployment(show_output=True)
```

Can anyone provide insight on this?

Answer (score 0):

```
{'Azure-cli-ml Version': '1.41.0', 'Error': WebserviceException: Message: ModelNotFound: Model with id [model1:9,model2:1] not found in provided workspace InnerException None ErrorResponse { "error": { "message": "ModelNotFound: Model with id [model1:9,model2:1] not found in provided workspace" } }}
```

The above-mentioned error is due to two reasons.

- The models were not available in the workspace created.

Creating workspace using CLI

`az group create -n myresourcegroup -l westus2`

`az ml workspace create -w myworkspace -g myresourcegroup`

`az ml folder attach -w myworkspace -g myresourcegroup`

for deploying multiple models using azure ML CLI, we need to use “-m” with the model’s name. We cannot add them into the workspace, as list element without mentioning **“-m”**.
**`--model -m`** : is the tag we need to add after the model's name

```
az ml model deploy --name multi-model --model -m '[model1:9,model2:1]' --compute-target 'aks-cpu' --ic inferenceConfig.json -e 'inference-env' --ev 6 --dc aksDeploymentConfig.json -g 'Workspace' --workspace-name 'MLWorkspace' --as true --mi 1 --ma 2 --overwrite -v
```